# datarow variable assign to dataset's table newrow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dataset, datarow

I'm trying to define a datarow to hold values and then add it to data set
indgv: datagridview with values in it 
dsdetails: a dataset with a table named details

```
If indgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim dr As DataRow
            dr = dsdetails.Tables("details").NewRow
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In indgv.Rows
                dr("mat") = row.Cells("icode").Value
                dr("dateoftrans") = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value
                dr("numoftrans") = transnum.Text
                dr("type") = 1
                dr("doc") = doctyp.SelectedValue
                dr("amount") = row.Cells("iamo").Value
                dsdetails.Tables("details").Rows.Add(dr)
            Next
            adpdetails.Update(dsdetails, "details")
        End If
```

running this causes the following error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

how to rephrase the declaration with 'New' to avoid the problen 
BTW : when using new as the following

```
Dim dr As New DataRow = dsdetails.Tables("details").NewRow
```

it shows design time error

> Type 'dsdetails.Tables' is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
If indgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    Dim tbl As DataTable = dsdetails.Tables("details")
    Dim dr As DataRow

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In indgv.Rows

        dr = tbl.NewRow 'Create a new row inside the loop!
        dr("mat") = row.Cells("icode").Value
        dr("dateoftrans") = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value
        dr("numoftrans") = transnum.Text
        dr("type") = 1
        dr("doc") = doctyp.SelectedValue
        dr("amount") = row.Cells("iamo").Value

        tbl.Rows.Add(dr)

    Next

    adpdetails.Update(tbl)

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to copy rows from one table to another, DataTable class has a Copy method you may want to use. It works like this:

```
Dim dtCopy As New DataTable()
dtCopy = dt.Copy()
```

If you have a datagridview control bound to a table, you could also use this form:

```
Dim dtCopy As New DataTable()
dtCopy = DirectCast(dataGridViewX1.DataSource, DataTable).Copy()
```

The [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) method will copy the datatable structure and the data.
If you want to copy the structure only without the data you could use [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the data in the row is mix of fields: some from the data grid and some from the form's controls.